# Python black screen when booting game

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the game window
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
size = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Set the title of the game window
pygame.display.set_caption("Clicker Game")

# Set the font for the score display and upgrade prices
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

# Set the initial score and click value
score = 0
click_value = 1

# Set the upgrade prices
upgrade1_price = 10
upgrade2_price = 50
upgrade3_price = 100

# Set the initial state of the shop menu and red button
shop_menu_open = False
red_button_visible = True

# Define the function to draw the shop menu
def draw_shop_menu():
    # Draw the background
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [200, 100, 400, 400])

    # Draw the upgrade items
    upgrade1_text = font.render(
        "Upgrade 1 (+"
        + str(click_value + 1)
        + " per click): "
        + str(upgrade1_price)
        + " clicks",
        True,
        BLACK,
    )
    upgrade1_rect = upgrade1_text.get_rect(center=(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, 225))
    screen.blit(upgrade1_text, upgrade1_rect)

    upgrade2_text = font.render(
        "Upgrade 2 (+"
        + str(click_value + 5)
        + " per click): "
        + str(upgrade2_price)
        + " clicks",
        True,
        BLACK,
    )
    upgrade2_rect = upgrade2_text.get_rect(center=(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, 300))
    screen.blit(upgrade2_text, upgrade2_rect)

    upgrade3_text = font.render(
        "Upgrade 3 (+"
        + str(click_value + 10)
        + " per click): "
        + str(upgrade3_price)
        + " clicks",
        True,
        BLACK,
    )
    upgrade3_rect = upgrade3_text.get_rect(center=(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, 375))
    screen.blit(upgrade3_text, upgrade3_rect)


# Main game loop
done = False
while not done:
    # Check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Check if the player clicked on the shop button to toggle the shop menu
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if mouse_pos[0] > 650 and mouse_pos[1] < 30:
                    shop_menu_open = not shop_menu_open
                    red_button_visible = not shop_menu_open
                elif (
                    not shop_menu_open
                    and red_button_visible
                    and mouse_pos[0] > 350
                    and mouse_pos[0] < 450
                    and mouse_pos[1] > 250
                    and mouse_pos[1] < 350
                ):
                    score += click_value
                elif shop_menu_open and mouse_pos[0] > 250 and mouse_pos[0] < 550:
                    # Check if the player clicked on an upgrade item to buy it
                    if (
                        mouse_pos[1] > 200
                        and mouse_pos[1] < 250
                        and score >= upgrade1_price
                    ):
                        score -= upgrade1_price
                        click_value += 1
                        upgrade1_price *= 2
                    elif (
                        mouse_pos[1] > 275
                        and mouse_pos[1] < 325
                        and score >= upgrade2_price
                    ):
                        score -= upgrade2_price
                        click_value += 5
                        upgrade2_price *= 2
                    elif (
                        mouse_pos[1] > 375
                        and mouse_pos[1] < 425
                        and score >= upgrade3_price
                    ):
                        score -= upgrade3_price
                        click_value += 10
                        upgrade3_price *= 2

    # Fill the background with black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw the red button
    if red_button_visible:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [350, 250, 100, 100])

# Draw the score
score_text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, WHITE)
score_rect = score_text.get_rect()
screen.blit(score_text, score_rect)


# Draw the shop menu if it is open
if shop_menu_open:
    draw_shop_menu()


# Update the display
pygame.display.update()


# Quit pygame
pygame.quit()
```

When I start the game I just see a black screen.

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

I tried changing the indentation of the code in various ways, because I know that indentation is important in Python, but I was unable to fix the problem this way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I edited the post so that it directly **asks a question** as expected here, and to cut out [conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) that we don't want in questions here. As for the issue: we don't [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) code for you here. If the problem is that you can't get anything to show up at all, then there is no point trying to show a bunch of game logic with no visible effect. Please read [mre].

Comment: For example, have you previously been able to make **any** Pygame project work, and show **anything besides** just popping up a black screen? If not, then **that is the actual problem**, and you should start by showing an attempt to get only that working. On the other hand, if you have been able to make it work before, then you should try to figure out **what is different** in this project - for example, by starting from what works, and gradually adding pieces of the logic **until you find something that causes the problem**.

Comment: that's an indentation problem, all lines starting from `screen.fill(BLACK)` need to have 8 spaces of indentation except the last line.

Comment: I had gotten it working, I watched some tutorials because this was my first game using pygame, so I was confused at first, but after looking around and watching some YouTube tutorials I had gotten it, I had put the black background in the wrong spot so it hadn't worked at first, also thanks for the help with future questions and thanks to Ahmed AEK for the help

Comment: I had seen your comment after I got it working, but thanks for replying with the fix for it